# directoryIterator has wrong "starting point"

Tags: php, iterator, directory

I have a recursive directory iterator looking like this:

```
function ReadFolderDirectory($dir,$listDir= array())
{
    $listDir = array();
    if($handler = opendir($dir))
    {
        while (($sub = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if ($sub != "." && $sub != ".." && $sub != "Thumb.db")
            {
                if(is_file($dir."/".$sub))
                {
                    $listDir[] = $sub;
                }elseif(is_dir($dir."/".$sub))
                {
                    $listDir[$sub] = ReadFolderDirectory($dir."/".$sub); 
                } 
            } 
        }    
        closedir($handler); 
    } 
    return $listDir;    
}
```

And I use it like this

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$path = $path.'/uploadedImages/';
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
$filesArray = ReadFolderDirectory($dir);
echo json_encode($filesArray);
```

Now when I try to set the starting point of the directory iteration, as you see I have added /uploadedImages/ to the path, but it seems to disregard that.

No matter if that is there or not, it always starts from the same directory as the php file is in, thus including also the index.php, ._index,php, and listing of course the folder uploadedImages itself.

Any thoughts what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your code, you have just to remove this code line :

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
```

**Explanation**

```
opendir(String $pathToDir) // expects a String, but you pass an Object as a parameter
```